# ESP8266 Micropython webserver with AJAX

Tags: android, python, ajax, esp8266, micropython

i have RC car project with ESP8266 12E running Micropython. ESP is in AP mode and it hosts HTML page that contains two sliders (one for steering and one for drive speed). Values of both sliders are sent by AJAX request every 200 milliseconds. When controlling with my laptop, everything works fine, on my old Android phone (HTC Desire 200, Android 4.0) it runs great too.
But, when I want to control the car with my current phone (Huawei P8 lite, Android 6.0), it runs for about 2 minutes and then it stops working and reconnects after while.

Does anyone know, what or where might be the issue?

Thanks for any replies.

Here is python code:

```
import socket
import machine

f = open('html.html')
html = f.read()
f.close()

servo = machine.PWM(machine.Pin(4), freq=50)
fwd = machine.PWM(machine.Pin(12), freq=50)
bwd = machine.PWM(machine.Pin(14), freq=50)

def speed(i):
    if i > 300:
        i = i-300
        fwd.duty(i)
        bwd.duty(0)
    elif i < -300:
        i = i*(-1)
        i = i-300
        fwd.duty(0)
        bwd.duty(i)
    else:
        fwd.duty(0)
        bwd.duty(0)

addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', 80)[0][-1]

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(addr)
s.listen(1)

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    request = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.sendall('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n')
    request = str(request)
    ix = request.find('X')
    iy = request.find('Y')
    iz = request.find('Z')
    if ix > 0 :
        ie = request.find(' ', ix)
        ValX = int(request[ix+1:iy])
        ValY = int(request[iy+1:iz])
        servo.duty(ValX)
        speed(ValY)           
    else:
        conn.sendall(html)
    conn.sendall('\n')
    conn.close()
```

And the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;' name='viewport'/>
    <title>Ferrari F430</title>
    <style>

    input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: black;
    }

    input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 5px;
    background: lightgrey;
    outline: none;
    position:absolute;
    }

    input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: black;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>       
    <input type='range' ontouchend='resetX()' onmouseup='resetX()' min='61' max='101' value='81' id='sliderX' style='width:50%; left:5%; top:50%;'>
    <input type='range' ontouchend='resetY()' onmouseup='resetY()' min='-1323' max='1323' value='0' id='sliderY' style='width:40%; -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); left:60%; top:50%;'>
      <script>

      function myFunction(){
        var x = document.getElementById("sliderX").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("sliderY").value;
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST","Val=X" + x + "Y" + y + "Z",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
      setInterval(myFunction, 200);

      function resetX(){
        document.getElementById("sliderX").value = 81; 
      }

      function resetY(){
        document.getElementById("sliderY").value = 0; 
      }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you phone should show you a notification which say somethink like, connected to a network without internet we two button, "stay connected" and another one. If you use it and click on stay connected it's good

Comment: @Yunnosch and co, I have copy paste my answer from notepad, but had not copy all the answer by error...
When I have checked my post and wanted to correct it. It was already delete ...